# Installing Heroku CLI on a mac

Tags: heroku, homebrew

Following the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli), I tried installing the Heroku CLI by typing the following into Terminal:

`brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku`

The installation seems to work successfully. However, when I then type `heroku --version`, or indeed any other Heroku command, I get the error message:

`zsh: command not found: heroku`

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after installing?

Comment: Just tried that; unfortunately it doesn't help!

Comment: can you output `$PATH`? if possible, maybe `brew doctor` output as well.